# javax.validation.Valid with Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I am using `@Valid` for validation during a form submission and encountered error that a property is null. I have a Country class which have properties such as `code`, `name` and `createdBy` all with their predefined values. When user load the page the loaded property on the form are only `code` and `name`. After user changes the value and perform submission the value of `createdBy`is null thus validation fails. I am thinking of storing createdBy value in a hidden field on html so the validation should pass. In view of security I think anyone can actually modify the hidden field value. Is there a better approach ? Will OpenSessionInViewFilter helps in any way ?

**UPDATED**

Sorry that I forgot to mention, the data the browser gets from the server is in form of JSON (List of json object). Before form submission a wrote a JavaScript to populate the form based on the chosen object (with ID) within a html table. So what I send to the server is basically

```
<input type="hidden" name="id"/>
<html:field name="code" labelCode="label.code" type="text"/>
<html:field name="name" labelCode="label.name" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Are you create the instance to the Country and put it on modeal and view map? If you retrieve this information, the createdBy filed must not be null... I don't see as hidden filed a good approach to do this. Anyway, it may help if you update your question with the source code.

Comment: Can't you simply remove the `@NotNull` on the `createdBy` property of your `Country` bean (or XML equivalent)?

Comment: Yes I can. I guess I will have to ensure the property is being set before insertion into the database.

Comment: You can also automatically add its value in the corresponding service or dao methods.

Comment: Actually you can set this filed using @PrePersist on private method at your Entity.